# Vectors: What is $T$ in $v^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I'm practicing linear algebra with matrices and vectors.

I've been given $2$ vectors $u = <2,5,1>$ and $v = <-1,4>$.

I am asked to work out $u.v^T$. I have no problem in working out the product of two matrices/vectors, I'm just confused by the $T$ in $u.v^T$?

Comment: it's the transpose

Comment: What is that? or should i google it

Comment: @Human Can you please explain me how your edit improved the formatting with respect to the previous edit?

Comment: @Surb , It's a subsequent edit. When I start editing your edit was not there, so I didn't edited your edits. I just edited the title of the original question.

Comment: @Surb, I have edited it more appropriately now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of $v$.

For example:
$$v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\qquad \implies \qquad v^T = (1,2) $$
Likewise,
$$ u= (3,4) \qquad \implies \qquad u^T=\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$$